# Vulkan: vkWaitForFences syncrhonizing access to VkDevice

Tags: vulkan

Is it necessary to synchronize access to the device handle when calling `vkWaitForFences`? The specification does not mention any need for this, but doesn't mention it being free-threaded, either. In some places, namely most of the `vkCreateXXX`, mention this as a requirement. Given the explicit nature of the spec, I'd expect more precise wording (rather than none at all in this case).

I suspect the answer is "no", but I am unable to trust my intuition with this API or implementations behind it.

It would be strange (useless, actually), if it is necessary to guard a call to this function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spec uses the terms "external synchronization" and "host synchronization" to talk about objects/parameters where the application must ensure non-concurrent use. The rules are described in [Section 2.5 "Threading Behavior"](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#fundamentals-threadingbehavior), and in the "Host Synchronization" block after most commands. Anything not listed can be used concurrently.

I'm not sure why you think that the device parameter is supposed to be externally synchronized for `vkCreate*`, I couldn't find something in the spec to support that. The device object is almost never externally synchronized.

None of the parameters to `vkWaitForFences` is listed as Host Synchronized. But the fence(s) passed to `vkQueueSubmit` and `vkResetFences` *are* host synchronized, so you can't pass a fence to one of those calls while there is another thread waiting for the fence. But you could have two threads waiting on the same fence, or one thread calling `vkGetFenceStatus` while another thread is waiting on it.

Comment: TBH I find "external synchronization" and "host synchronization" terms confusing too, considering there is almost nothing in Vulkan internally synchronized. Maybe it is helpful to think of every command parameter as "read accessed", and every one listed in "host synchronization" as "write accessed". read-read does not require synchronization; write-read and write-write does.

Comment: Yes, thinking in terms of "write accessed" is helpful, that's what I do too. Except in a few cases, when a command *requires* write access to a parameter, that parameter is externally synchronized. But many implementations may need incidental write access to parameters that don't change the API-visible state of that parameter. So those aren't externally synchronized (with a few exceptions), and will have to be internally synchronized if the implementation needs ordered access. Many of the VkDevice commands fall into that category.